# Nested Multinomial Logit Estimation

Tags: multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit, nested-models

I am trying to estimate a nested multinomial logit model for transportation mode - the decision tree of how consumers choose a travel mode for a trip.

One way of estimating the nested multinomial logit is bottom up. By first estimating the conditional probilities (twigs) $$P(Mode_i|Air),P(Mode_i|Ground)$$ using a standard multinomial logit model and then estimating the marginal probabilities (branches)   $$P(Air),P(Ground)$$

**My Question**: How do you estimate the conditional probabilities (twigs) $P(Mode_i|Air),P(Mode_i|Ground)$ when invididuals in the dataset may have choosen an alternative(choice) not in that twig's choice set?

For example in the **Ground** option, Air is not in the choice set. But some individuals in my dataset chose Air and none of the three alternatives Train,Bus, or Car. So should I remove them from the sample when estimating the Ground branch? If not how you do you estimate this model backward?

I am using the following dataset and model in R

```
data("TravelMode",package="AER")
TravelMode <- mlogit.data(TravelMode,choice="choice",shape="long",alt.var="mode",chid.var="individual")
TravelMode$avinc <- with(TravelMode,(mode=='air')*income)
nl.TM <- mlogit(choice ~ wait + gcost + avinc, TravelMode, reflevel = "car", 
                nests = list(fly = "air", ground = c("train", "bus", "car")),
                unscaled=TRUE)
summary(nl.TM)
```

Page 35
http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf#page=67&zoom=100,58,266

[image]